# MLE of number of colors

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I'm looking at this question and the solution given and I understand it, but I'm unable to see where I'm going wrong.

The question states that there are $k$ equally frequent colors and we do not know $k.$ We examine four smarties and notice that they are red, green, red, orange. We wish to find the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{k}$.

The solution given is that $$\text{lik}(k) = \frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{k^3} $$ since we are looking at the probability that the second and fourth color differs from the first and the third is equal to the first. This can easily seen to be maximized when $\hat{k} = 5$.

My issue is why we are looking at the probability that the second colour and fourth are different from the first.

If we instead look at the probability as the probability of seeing R, G, R, O given there are $k$ colours then the likelihood function is just $$\text{lik}(k)=\frac{1}{k^4}$$ since all sequences of colours are equally likely. This is maximized when $k=3$ as there must at least be 3 different colors.

I can sort of see that I'm going wrong somewhere as my answer is independent of the sequence we get, but where exactly am I going wrong? And why is the correct interpretation to ignore the actual sequence we get and only look at the differentiation between the colors?

EDIT: I'm trying to reimagine a question with $k$ being the maximum positive integer allowed and we see a specific sequence 3, 1, 3, 7. In that case I believe my interpretation would probably be correct. So it must have something to do with the fact that colors aren't ordered, but I'm not able to convince myself exactly what the issue is.

Comment: "Why we are looking at the probability that the second colour and fourth are different from the first.[?]"  Because these are the most informative draws.  The MLE hypothesis after the first draw is that there is one colour.  This is immediately contradicted by the second draw which forces ${}\geq 2$ colours.  The third draw only informs that there are not "too many" colors (otherwise repetition is unlikely).  Finally, the fourth draw forces that there are ${}\geq 3$ colours.  The most informative draws are the second and fourth.

Comment: Idk in other such MLE questions the likelihood function is always just the probability of seeing *that* very sequence. For example in iid U(0, t) samples with t unknown the likelihood is just $\frac{1}{t^n} \cdot 1_{\text{max} X_i \leq t}$. You don't look at whether the third sample is near the first one or something. Not sure what's different here.

Comment: This is not the likelihood of *that* very sequence.  This is the likelihood of seeing any permutation of *that* very sequence.  Relative to the Question (about colours), the first member of that sequence does not establish a value from which deviation of subsequent values are informative.  What's the probability of getting "red" as the first colour when you only make one draw?  Well, it's $1/1$ in the sequence you have.  Non-red for the second?  $(k-1)/k$.  Repetition of whatever was the first colour? $1/k$.   Non-red, non-green for the fourth?  $(k-2)/k$.

Comment: Or to rephrase: for uniform sampling, repetitions of the first value are completely uninformative and lesser values are completely uninformative.  Only the first value and values greater than the first value can be informative about $t$.  For the sequence of colours, the first color is uninformative -- you already know there are beads having at least one colour.  Informative draws are any colour not already seen.

Comment: We're not just looking at the probability that the second and fourth colors differ from the first and the third is equal to the first, but also that the second and fourth differ from each other.

Comment: ‘ We examine four smarties’ … Perfect MSE autobot!

Answer (score 1):

We know in advance that there is at least one color. Thus when we observe the color of the first one we are seeing an event of probability $1,$ regardless of what $k$ is.

The larger $k$ is, the more probable it is that the second differs from the first. That probability is $(k-1)/k.$

The larger $k$ is, the less probable it is that the third is the same as the first. That probability is $1/k.$

Then the probability that the fourth differs from the two colors observed so far is $(k-2)/k.$